# WordPress просмотр темы

Tags: wordpress

Есть проблема, захожу в репозиторий тем WP, выбираю любую тему, нажимаю просмотр, и мне всегда вместо главной страницы, показывает страницу блога этой темы. В настройках чтения у меня стоит главная как статичная страница, а не страница записей. 
Что я не так делаю ?(

Comment: Демки нужно смотреть на оф сайтах производителей.

Answer (score 0):

Превью показывает содержимое сайта `https://wp-themes.com/` с выбранной вами темой. Никакого отношения к настройкам вашей темы он отношения не имеет.

Comment: Дело в том, что на картинке одно содержимое, когда нажимаю просмотр темы там уже совсем другое содержимое темы, вот я предположил, что это зависит от настроек моей темы